# How to test value of XML tag attribute within an if statement

Tags: python, xml, attributes, lxml

Is it possible to test the `value` of a `XML` tag's attribute as part of an `if` statement?

For example, I have a `XML` with the following tag:

```
<Cell ss:StyleID="HeadTableTitle" ss:MergeAcross="1"><Data ss:Type="String">Administrative Data</Data></Cell>
```

I am trying to test whether the attribute `ss:StyleID` == `HeadTableTitle` in that `<Cell>` tag

```
from lxml import etree

f_path = 'data store/cortex_full.xml'  # enter path of xml file
epoch = 0  # set epoch window size (seconds) for smoothing data (set to 0 to use raw)

with open(f_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
root = etree.parse(f)

namespaces = {'o': 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office',
          'x': 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel',
          'ss': 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet'}

ws = root.xpath('/ss:Workbook/ss:Worksheet', namespaces=namespaces)
if len(ws) > 0:
    tables = ws[0].xpath('./ss:Table', namespaces=namespaces)
    if len(tables) > 0:
        rows = tables[0].xpath('./ss:Row', namespaces=namespaces)
        for row in rows:
            cells = row.xpath('./ss:Cell', namespaces=namespaces)
            if len(cells) == 1: # skip if row have multiple 'cells'
                if cells[0].attrib('./@ss:StyleID', namespaces=namespaces) == 'HeadTableTitle':
                    ## execute some code ##
```

However, when I execute the last line in the code it throws a `TypeError: 'lxml.etree._Attrib' object is not callable`

Comment: `attrib` is a dictionary. Use square brackets, not parentheses.

Comment: if I run `if cells[0].attrib['./@ss:StyleID', namespaces=namespaces] == 'HeadTableTitle':` throws a syntax error on `namespaces=namespaces`, if remove namespaces, throws `KeyError: './ss:StyleID'`

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `xpath` four times? Not sure if the whole logic could be squeezed into single xpath expression, but two should be enough, with much smaller number of `if ...`.

Comment: New to coding, have been following examples on here and other sites.  There is other code that happens after this but that uses the `<row>` tags also, so you are likely correct. Also there will always be a `worksheet`, `workbook` and `table` hence the checks `if ... > 0:` are technically redundant.  Could I refer directly with `rows = root.xpath('/ss:Workbook/ss:Worksheet/ss:Table/ss:Row, ns=ns)`?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much what I had in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value of an attribute, you can use `element.attrib['key']` or `element.get('key')`.

In both cases you need to use the full namespace URI if the attribute is bound to a namespace.

```
if cells[0].get('{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}StyleID') == 'HeadTableTitle':
```

Comment: I think I got to the same fix just as you posted that.  Odd that everywhere else you can simply put `./ss` but when referring directly to the attributes you have to put the full path.